# Can image-dired track renamed files?

Tags: dired, files, images

I would like to view images using `image-dired`, then rename them. What I do at the moment:

- Open `image-dired` with my directory of choice.
- Mark an image that I want to rename.
- In the corresponding `dired+` buffer, I run `wdired-change-to-wdired-mode`, then rename the marked file.

Now `image-dired` still shows the renamed file, but it cannot be marked again in case I want that. The reason is that `image-dired` doesn't know about the rename.

*Is there a way to rename images so that `image-dired` picks up the changes? Or is there a way to quickly refresh `image-dired` to pick up all changes in the current directory?*

Comment: If you refresh the buffer with `g`, aka `revert-buffer`, does that fix it?

Comment: @lawlist Running `revert-buffer` in `*image-dired*` gives "Buffer does not seem to be associated with any file" (makes sense). `g` in `*image-dired*` is not for refresh.